# Element css Height returns 1 after jQuery slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In the javascript below the following line should find the height of the dropdown-container element in it's `slideDown()` / visible state. However, it appears to be doing the opposite when the button is clicked and the dropdown expands the height returned is 1 (I have tested this by uncommenting the line at the end of the function). When the button is clicked again to collapse the dropdown the height is, for example, 681. Why is this the case and is there any way to assess the expanded height correctly within this function when the button is clicked to expand the dropdown container please?

`$(this).next(".dropdown-container").css("height")`

Here is the javascript in full:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dropdown = $(".dropdown-btn");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
        dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            $(".dropdown-btn").not(this).removeClass("active");
            $(".dropdown-container").slideUp();
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                $(this).next(".dropdown-container").slideDown();
                if (Modernizr.mq('(max-height: 750px)') || $(this).next(".dropdown-container").css("height").replace(/px/, "") > ($(document).height() - 132 - 176)) {
                    $(".dropdown-btn").not(this).slideUp();
                }
            }
             else {
                    $(".dropdown-btn").not(this).slideDown();
            }

//$('a').text($(this).next(".dropdown-container").css("height").replace(/px/, ""));
});
```

Comment: Because `slideDown` is kind of “asynchronous”? You will have to wait until it is _done_ showing the full element, before you can query its actual height.

Comment: To add to the above, this is why the `slideX()` methods have a callback. Put your logic in there. http://api.jquery.com/slideDown

Comment: Thank you both, @RoryMcCrossan adding the code in the callback worked a treat once I had updated the `this` logic relative to the container instead of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments above, the height needed to be assessed within the callback function, which is the second option in the `slideDown` method. As the code was moved the `this` logic also needed to be updated to be relative to the container instead of the button. Below is the code that was updated:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).next(".dropdown-container").slideDown("slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
        if (Modernizr.mq('(max-height: 750px)') || $(this).css("height").replace(/px/, "") > ($(document).height() - 132 - 176)) {
            $(".dropdown-btn").not($(this).prev(".dropdown-btn")).slideUp();
        }
    });
}
```